# truffle deploy live | transaction not mined within 750 seconds

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my smart contract to the live ETH network. I've done the same process on rinkeby and it works fine. However during the block mining phase it times out and gives the error:
" transaction not mined within 750 seconds deployment error"
Is there a way to increase the length of the deployment process? Or disable timeouts? Or make it go faster?
Thanks!

Comment: Check if the gas price is too low, a lower gas price will cause your transaction to have lower priority. Check the gas limit, a gas limit closer to the block gas limit might cause delays even if you use only a fraction. A previous transaction still in pending state, transaction are processed in order. Not enough ether to pay for the transaction, you need at least `gasLimit * gasPrice + value`.

Comment: web3 wait max of 50 blocks, which is actully a very long time, Increase your gas price

Comment: Hii @Andrew  did you get the solution for your problem, please let me know i am having the query

Comment: Thank you @Ismael so much! Sorry for not replying sooner - the issue was I had the gas limit at the maximum. I reduced the limit to 1/4 what it was an it worked fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Narendra try changing the gas limit away from the default max

Comment: @AndrewLewis Please add your solution as an answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was I had the gas limit at the maximum. I reduced the limit to 1/4 what it was and it worked fine.